# How to get proper Strophe.js callback on successful connection

Tags: javascript

I am developing a generic library for communicating xmpp users through BOSH service. I use Strophe.js

I cannot understand why in class BoshCommunicator method onConnect I have a Strophe object, but not BoshCommunicator as expected.

When I console.log(this) I get Object { service="http://myboshim/http-bind", jid="aivaras37@myboshim/29785298701381498988721337", rid=4092107607, more...}

Also, before establishing connection I set listener property for BoshCommunicator class. When I console.log(this.listener) I get undefined, but if I console.log(this.listener) in connect() method I get expected dump of listener object. Can you explain me how to get initialized BoshCommunicator in BoshCommunicator.prototype.onConnect()? Also please explain why I loose my object and get Strophe instead.

Here is a particular code I use:

```
function BoshCommunicator(boshUri, host)
{
    this.connection = null;
    this.boshUri = null;
    this.host = null;
    this.listener = null;
    this.setBoshUri(boshUri);
    this.setHost(host);
}

BoshCommunicator.prototype.setBoshUri = function(boshUri)
{
    this.boshUri = boshUri;
};

BoshCommunicator.prototype.setHost = function(host)
{
    this.host = host;
};

BoshCommunicator.prototype.setListener = function(listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
    this.listener.setListenHost(this.host);
};

BoshCommunicator.prototype.connect = function(jid, jpass)
{
    this.connection = new Strophe.Connection(this.boshUri);
    this.connection.connect(jid, jpass, this.onConnect);
};

BoshCommunicator.prototype.onConnect = function(status)
{
    if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
        console.log("Send me messages!");
        console.log(this); // dumps strophe object. Paste from console: Object { service="http://myboshim/http-bind", jid="aivaras37@myboshim/29785298701381498988721337", rid=4092107607, more...}
        console.log(this.listener); // undefined - how come?
        this.connection.addHandler(this.listener.onReceivedMessage, null, 'message', null, null,  null);
        this.connection.send($pres().tree());
    }
};

function MessageListener()
{
    this.host = null;
}

MessageListener.prototype.setListenHost = function(host)
{
    this.host = host;
};

function ReceivedMessageNotify()
{
    MessageListener.call(this);
}

ReceivedMessageNotify.prototype = new MessageListener();
ReceivedMessageNotify.prototype.constructor = ReceivedMessageNotify;
ReceivedMessageNotify.prototype.onReceivedMessage = function(message)
{
    console.log(message);
    var elems = message.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var body = elems[0];
    if (Strophe.getText(body).length > 0) {
        this.sendNewMessageNotify(message.getAttribute('from'), Strophe.getText(body));
    }
    return true;
};

ReceivedMessageNotify.prototype.sendNewMessageNotify = function(sender, messageBody)
{
    alert("New message: " + sender + " wrote: " + messageBody);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var communicator = new BoshCommunicator('http://myboshim/http-bind', 'myboshim');
    communicator.setListener(new ReceivedMessageNotify());
    communicator.connect('jabberId', 'accPasswd');
});
```

Comment: This probably needs to be moved to stackoverflow.  You're more likely to get good answers and comments there anyway.  This site focuses more on general concepts of software development, whereas stackoverflow deals with real technical issues in code and stuff like that.

Comment: Panzercrisis, how can I migrate my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at following code mentioned below:

Usage Instructions:

```js
var demo = DEMOPROJECT.Xmpp.init();
demo.connction.connect(username, password, function() {
    //success callback

}, function() {
    //errror callback

});
```

```js
(function(MODULE) {

    "use strict";

    MODULE.Xmpp = function() {

        var _self;
        function _getInstance(xmpp_bosh_url) {
            try {
                return new Strophe.Connection(xmpp_bosh_url);
            } catch (e) {
                _self.log("Strophe Connection Failed: " + e.message);
            }
        };
        function _onConnect(status, callback, errorCallback) {
            var error = '';
            switch (status) {
                case Strophe.Status.ERROR:
                    error = "Error: " + Strophe.Status.ERROR;
                    break;
                case Strophe.Status.CONNECTING:
                    _self.log('Connecting...');
                    break;
                case Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL:
                    error = "Connection Failed: " + Strophe.Status.ERROR;
                    break;
                case Strophe.Status.AUTHENTICATING:
                    _self.log('Authenticating client...');
                    break;
                case Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL:
                    error = "Authorization Fail: " + Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL;
                    break;
                case Strophe.Status.CONNECTED:
                    _self.log('Connected...');
                    _onConnected(callback);
                    break;
                case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING:
                    _self.log('Diconnecting...');
                    break;
                case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED:
                    _self.log('Diconnected...');
                    break;
                case Strophe.Status.ATTACHED:
                    _self.log('Attached...');
                    break;
            }
            if (error) {
                _onError(errorCallback, status, error);
            }
            return true;
        };
        function _onError(errorCallback, errorCode, error) {
            _self.disconnect();
            (typeof errorCallback == 'function') ? errorCallback.call(this, errorCode, error): '';
        };
        function _onConnected(callback) {
            (typeof callback == 'function') ? callback.call(this): '';
        };

        return {
            init: function(xmpp_bosh_url) {
                _self = this;
                if (!_self.connection) {
                    _self.connection = _getInstance(xmpp_bosh_url);
                    if (MODULE.config.debug) {
                        this.debugInfo("html");
                    }
                    return _self;
                }
                return _self;
            },
            connect: function(userName, password, callback, errorCallback) {
                _self.userName = userName;
                _self.password = password;
                this.connection.connect(userName, password, function(status) {
                    _onConnect(status, callback, errorCallback);
                });
            },
            isConnected: function() {
                return _self.connection.connected;
            },
            getType: function() {
                return _self.connection.servtype;
            },
            getDomain: function() {
                return _self.connection.domain;
            },
            sendMessage: function(message) {
                if (!message) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    this.connection.sendIQ(message.tree(), function(data) {
                        console.log("message success");
                    }, function(err) {
                        console.log("message errror");
                    });
                }
            },
            removeListener: function(listener) {
                this.connection.deleteHandler(listener);
            },
            disconnect: function() {
                if (this.connection !== null) {
                    this.connection.disconnect();
                    this.connection.flush();
                    this.connection = null;
                }
            },
            debugInfo: function(stream) {
                console.log(message);
            }
        }
    }();

    
})(window.DEMOPROJECT = window.DEMOPROJECT || {});


var demo = DEMOPROJECT.Xmpp.init();
demo.connction.connect(username, password, function() {
    //success callback

}, function() {
    //errror callback

});
```